# Problem with indexAction method in IndexController class

Tags: php, zend-framework

Im using Zend Framework v1.11.0.I have the following code in my IndexController.php.

```
<?php
 class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {
  public function indexAction()
  {
   echo 'Web site home';
  }

 }
?>
```

But, if i navigate to:http://projectname i get a blank page and if i go to:http://projectname/index i get Error 404.

However,if i replace the indexAction word by the word init and then navigate to:http://projectname i get 'Web site home' echoed.

How can this be fixed ?

Thank You.

Comment: use die() after echo statement to verify your application flow is correct. make sure you have error_reporting enabled (blank page should have some errors on it)

Comment: No you should put display_errors = 1 in application.ini and then update your question with your error message

Answer (score 6):

You're probably getting a 404 because you don't have view for the action created, you normally don't `echo` content form a controller, you just set up variables for the view. IF you're just doing a quick test then you can use an `exit` statement right after your `echo`.

Normally it would look like this:

in Index `application/controllers/indexController.php`

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $this->view->message = 'Web site home';
}
```

in `application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml`

```
<?php if(isset($this->message)): ?>
  <?php echo  $this->message; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```